# C# OLEDB connection for EXCEL not working on loop

Tags: c#, excel, oledbconnection, oledbdatareader

1-I am having a strange problem.

Requirement: read a list of excel files on a folder and store the content on a dataset.

What I have written:
**Button click:**

```
protected void btnUploadExcelFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strPath);
            foreach (string strFile in strFiles)
            {
                ClsExcelUpload objExcelUpload = new ClsExcelUpload();
                string szConnectionString1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + strFile + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
                objExcelUpload.ReadExcel(szConnectionString1, strFile);

            }
}
```

**function ReadExcel:**

```
public string ReadExcel(string szConnectionString, string strFile)
    {
        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection();
        objConn.ConnectionString = szConnectionString;
        objConn.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter DAobjBasicInfo = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DAobjBasicInfo = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", objConn);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DAobjBasicInfo.Fill(dt1);
        objConn.Close();
        objConn.Dispose();
        return "";
    }
```

**Problem:**
The szConnectionString gets updated with the new filename set through the loop but when the OleDbDataAdapter opens the objConn, it looks for the Excel file which is already deleted. and the datatable everytime gets the first file data everytime.

This is the strangest thing I have ever seen as I am not able to identify the area of problem why the oledbconnection is not getting updated.

---

entire code:

using System.Data;

using System.Data.OleDb;

```
    protected void btnUploadExcelFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadedFile\") + file.FileName);

            }
        }
    string strPath = Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadedFile\"));
    string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strPath);
    foreach (string strFile in strFiles)
    {
        ClsExcelUpload objExcelUpload = new ClsExcelUpload();
        string szConnectionString1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + strFile + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
      string result=  ReadExcel(szConnectionString1, strFile);

    }
}


    public string ReadExcel(string szConnectionString, string strFile)
    {
        OleDbConnection objConn = new OleDbConnection();
        objConn.ConnectionString = szConnectionString;
        objConn.Open();

        OleDbDataAdapter DAobjBasicInfo = new OleDbDataAdapter();
        DAobjBasicInfo = new OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", objConn);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        DAobjBasicInfo.Fill(dt1);
        objConn.Close();
        objConn.Dispose();
        File.Delete(strFile);
        return "";
    }
```

---

**Further analysis on this strange issue:**
I would try to explain in more detail.
I have one FileUpload control which allows multiple files to select and upload.
a command button which copies the posted file through FileUpload to a specified location.
Upto here everything works as expected.
Now I have the code written on the same command button to read the excel file which is copied.
The first file reads correctly.
while reading the second file it finds the same data.

Now to test it further. I have moved the file read code to a different command button. Now I did 2 tests.
Test 1. Upload 2 files using file upload
Click on command button 1 to copy the posted files to spefified location
click on Command button 2 to loop through the files on copied folder and read the
files.
Result: Same issue, reading second file it gets the same data.
Test 2:
Run the application. Do not select and upload any file. Manually copy the same to
files to the specified location.
click the command button 2 to read the files.
File reads correctly.

its very clear there is nothing wrong with the function to read files. When File Upload is working there must be some conflict in memory management. I wonder whats my alternative to the requirement.

Comment: I suggest you to use the debugger to understand what happens in this code. By the way, the DataTable _dt1_ is a local object that gets destroyed everytime the code exits the _ReadExcel_ method

Comment: Are you sure the `szConnectionString` in `ReadExcel` is what you think? Did you debug? PS You don't need to `objConn.Dispose` when you are returning from a method. You shouldn't assign `DaObjBasicInfo` twice for no reason, throwing away the empty `OleDbDataAdapter`.

Comment: in debugging I get the szConnectionString updated with the new string containing next excel file in the folder. But when it loads the datatable is gets the old file data which is already deleted from the location.

Comment: When looping, make sure you are only looking at XLS or XLSX file extension. I think OLEDB might create a hidden file when opening a sheet.

Comment: if will be great if anyone can try this simple method. put 2 files in a folder. use the button click method to read the files in a for loop. process one file at a time and use dledbDataadapter to load the first sheet data into a data table or dataset. I fear its a functional defect of dataadapter.

Comment: I kept the folder empty and it contains only 2 files that I have picked using the fileupload.

Comment: This is what I have done to copy the files to the specified folder. HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
            {
                HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadedFile\") + file.FileName);

                }

            }

Comment: objConn in textvisualizer for first file:Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='D:\GQA Project 2\ExcelLoader\ExcelLoader\UploadedFile\1.xls';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"                                                   objConn in textvisualizer for second file:                 Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='D:\GQA Project 2\ExcelLoader\ExcelLoader\UploadedFile\2.xls';Extended Properties="Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"

Comment: Why are you passing _strFile_ to ReadExcel? It is not used inside that method.

Comment: I have passed it to delete from the source location. For better clarify on the issue i have removed those lines related to file handing.

Comment: That's not good. In this way we cannot see what is your real code. And given the claimed problem I think it is better that you provide that whole code you have written. The code above shown cannot have that kind of behavior. Another suggestion is to clear your solution

Comment: added the entire code

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved. There's nothing wrong with the read excel. The problem is saving the posted file to specified location.

```
protected void btnUploadExcelFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile file = files[i];
        if (file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            FileUploadExcel.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadedFile\") + file.FileName);

        }
    }
string strPath = Path.GetFullPath(Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadedFile\"));
string[] strFiles = Directory.GetFiles(strPath);
foreach (string strFile in strFiles)
{
    ClsExcelUpload objExcelUpload = new ClsExcelUpload();
    string szConnectionString1 = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='" + strFile + "';Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;\"";
  string result=  ReadExcel(szConnectionString1, strFile);

}
```

}

```
        }
    }
```

it was reading and copying the same file with different name.So While reading from specified location it was reading same data from different files.

the corrected function as follows

```
        protected void btnUploadExcelFiles_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> LstStrPriExcelUploadError = new List<string>();
        HttpFileCollection files = Request.Files;
        foreach (HttpPostedFile uploadedFile in FileUploadExcel.PostedFiles)
        {
            string fn = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(uploadedFile.FileName);
            string SaveLocation = Server.MapPath(@"~\UploadedFile\") + "\\" + fn;

            uploadedFile.SaveAs(SaveLocation);
        }
    }
```